# Flutter : Dropdown Issues

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

As soon as I select a value from my dropdown this error appears

'package: flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart/: Failed assertion: line 855 pos 15: 'item == bull || item.isEmpty || value == null|| item.where((DropdownMenuItemitem){ retuen item.value == value;)}.length ==1':There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Category 1. Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

How can I rectify it?

And here is my code. It would be a great help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
String valueChoose;
List _listItem = ["Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4"];
List _listItem1 = [
"Sub Category 1",
"Sub Category 2",
"Sub Category 3",
"Sub Category 4"
];
List _listItem2 = ["CRIS", "ADMINISTRATION", "ZONE", "DEPARTMENT"];

var selectedState;
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Feedback"),
      centerTitle: true,
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      ),
    ),
    body: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Form(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Category"),
                    DropdownButton(
                      hint: Text("Select"),
                      items: _listItem
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: valueItem,
                          child: Text(valueItem),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (selectedAccountType) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedState = selectedAccountType;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selectedState,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("SUBCATEGORY"),
                    DropdownButton(
                      hint: Text("Select"),
                      items: _listItem1
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem1) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: valueItem1,
                          child: Text(valueItem1),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (selectedAccountType) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedState = selectedAccountType;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selectedState,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("MARKED TO"),
                    DropdownButton(
                      hint: Text("Select"),
                      items: _listItem2
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((valueItem2) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: valueItem2,
                          child: Text(valueItem2),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (selectedAccountType) {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedState = selectedAccountType;
                        });
                      },
                      value: selectedState,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 00, 70, 00),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Describe your problem here.",
                        ),
                        maxLength: 1000,
                        maxLines: 5,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                ButtonTheme(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    ));
   }
   }
```

Comment: the problem is this variable ```selectedState``` youre using them on the 3 dropdowns. And it should also not to be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you are using the `selectedState` variable for all `DropdownMenu` widget. And this isn't practical and it could lead to unexpected behavior and bugs. You should define a separate variable for each `DropdownMenu`.

Another problem is the way you are initializing the `selectedState` variable.
You are doing this: `var selectedState;`, without specifying a value so it gets a value of `null` by default.
However, the initial value of the `selectedState` varibale has to be one of the options of the `DropdownMenu`.
For example if these `List<String> options = <String>["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"];` are your options for the `DropdownMenu`, then you would have to initialize the `selectedState` variable like this for example: `var selectedState = "Option 1";`.

And the error is gone!